# Selenium RC: How to click link appears in grid?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm using Selenium RC and created all scripts in java (Using Junit test case)

I want to click one grid column having "Edit" link. 
My code is look like,

```
selenium.click("//table[@id='ctl00_POMSContentPlaceHolder_gvBillingCompany']//tr["+gRow+"]//td["+gCol+"]");
```

`gRow` and `gCol` are defined as integers and their values vary as moving to next row/column.

Please let me know if anything needs to be done in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- You probably want to click on the link (`<a>`), not the cell.
- Children selectors need a single slash: `//parent/child`.
- I'm pretty sure you need `tbody` there - it is added implicidly by browsers:
  `//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a[1]`
- You may have better luck with a css selector:
  `css=table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) a`

Comment: +1 although he does not need to add `tbody` if he writes `//table//tr[2]` as the `//` looks for a descendant not only in the next deeper level, but in all deeper levels. This can make a mess in nested tables though...

Comment: hey Kobi, I include "/tbody" and it works....thank you thank you thank you....woooopppppyyyyyyyy..... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Adding `tbody` **may** make the locator more fragile. Also, your CSS selector example has a typo - you've used `tr` twice instead of `td` in the second instance.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks. I agree, it also has potential problems. That's one of the reasons I suggested the css way.

Comment: Dave - you may be right...but I am new to selenium RC and I do not have any idea to implement css.
Kobi - if this "tbody" is not much safe then can you please give me more description about this CSS one.
Thanks.

Comment: @Saara - it is a bit more fragile because it depends greatly on the structure of your page, and because it's possible a browser wouldn't add the `tbody` tag (though afaik they do). A CSS locator can be more general (for example, if you have a class on the link or cell, or it has an id). CSS locators are recommended: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html - Quote: `Most experienced Selenium users recommend CSS as their locating strategy of choice as it’s considerably faster than XPath and can find the most complicated objects in an intrinsic HTML document.`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
selenium.click("xpath=id('ctl00_POMSContentPlaceHolder_gvBillingCompany')/descendant::tr[" +gRow+ "]/descendant::td["+gCol+"]");
```

The following is from http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#path-abbrev

In XPath, `//` is shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` but the location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant para element; the former selects all descendant para elements that are the first para children of their parents.